# Cómo crear parámetros opcionales?

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo agregar parámetros opcionales?, ya que un problema que tengo a la hora de hacer esto, es que si tengo una función que espera, ciertos parámetros, por ejemplo:

```
function(a,b,c)
```

Si no defino el parámetro `a`, el parámetro `b` tomará el lugar de ese parámetro y `c` el parámetro de `b`, entonces **como puedo hacer para que conserven sus lugares** ?, mi ejemplo en el que fallo:

```js
function show(a,b,funcion){
 console.log(`Al pasar menos parámetros, b queda como la función, aquí puede verse:
 
 ${b}`);
 var sumaA = typeof a === 'undefined' ? 15 : a;
 var sumaB = typeof b === 'undefined' ? 20 : b;
 var aEjecutar = typeof funcion !== 'function' ? 
                 false : funcion;                   
if(!aEjecutar) return false;
else aEjecutar(sumaA,sumaB);
}

/*
show(15,20,function(a,b){ // ==>  Funciona correcto, ya que se pasan todos los argumentos.
    console.log(a+b);
});
*/
show(5,function(a,b){ // Funciona INCORRECTO, ya que no se pasan todos.
    console.log(a+b);
});
```

Comment: Solo como comentario, si no pasas todos los parámetros `a` no pasa a ser `b`, ni `b` pasa a ser `c`. En el orden que los mandas, así se van asignando los parámetros, `a = 5, b = function f()` Imprime todas tus variables y verás a lo que me refiero

Comment: Sé lo que sucede, el problema  es que nosé como solucionarlo, y a eso mismo me refiero. Que sea "opcional", osea que si defino 5,function, el 5 sea a, b tome como undefined y que el parámetro "funcion" siga tomando la funcion y no quede indefinido

Comment: ¿Que tanta cantidad de casos quieres cubrir con tu función, es decir el número de parámetros que se lleguen a enviar y además el tipo de cada uno de estos? Para que tu función haga las asignaciones según los datos que reciba

Comment: @EduardoSebastian No voy a publicar una respuesta pero te dejo este código que elabore rápido tal vez te sirva: http://jsbin.com/josebiwilu/1/edit?js,console Nota: viendo que estas usando ES6 utilice el rest operator

Comment: lo que no entiendo es por que quieres hacer una funcion que te pase la funcion los parametros deseados, si igual para ejecutar ese show nuevamente solicitara los parametros

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Una opción que permite omitir argumentos o cambiarles de orden, es ponerle nombre en la llamada a la función `miFuncion({ param1: 10, param2: 25});`. Así pasamos un objeto en llamada y vamos a hacer algo ingenioso en el encabezado de la definición de la función para que salgan los parámetros como lista en lugar de uno solo: `function miFuncion({param1, param2}={}) { //código }`. Aquí debajo un ejemplo:

```js
function miFuncion({velocidad, masa}={}, miFuncion){
    if (typeof(miFuncion) ==="function"){
    return miFuncion(velocidad,masa);
    }else
    return (velocidad==null ? 1 : velocidad) * (masa == null ? 1 : masa);
}

var resultado = miFuncion({ velocidad : 10, masa : 80});
console.log(resultado); //800

resultado = miFuncion({ velocidad : 10 });
console.log(resultado); //10 porque masa es 1

resultado = miFuncion({ masa : 80});
console.log(resultado); //80 porque velocidad es 1

//pasando la funcion a ejecutar
miFuncion({ velocidad : 10, masa : 80} ,function(velocidad,masa){ 
    console.log(velocidad+masa);
});
miFuncion({ masa : 80} ,function(velocidad,masa){ 
    console.log(velocidad - masa);
});
```

Pero la solución mas sencilla es pasar `null` o `undefined` al llamar a la función, así los parámetros conservan su lugar. Si quieres ignorar todos los parámetros hacia la derecha entonces simplemente los omites.

```
var miFuncion = function(a,b,c,d){
    //código
};
```

Y en la llamada hacemos `miFuncion(null, 10, null, 5)` o bien `miFuncion(5)` que pasa el valor 5 para `a` y null para el resto.

Comment: Es una opción muy buena, pero permíteme una corrección: JSON != objeto javascript. JSON es un string con un formato especial, y no conviene mezclar ambos conceptos

Comment: @PabloLozano, correcto, JSON es la notación usada, no el objeto. Si quieres puedes editar mi respuesta.

Comment: Una ventaja de esta solución es que puedes añadir parámetros en futuras versiones de tu función manteniendo fácilmente la retrocompatibilidad

Answer (score 6):

La idea de mi solución sería obtener los argumentos en una lista y ver el número de argumentos que se pasan, asignando los valores por defecto a las variables "que faltan".

También comparamos los tipos de las variables para ver si se ha ingresado los tipos de parámetros deseados (**`number`** para `a y b`; **`function`** para `fn`) y devolvemos false si no coinciden con lo deseado (Como haces en tu ejemplo):

```js
function show(...args){
  let a, b, fn;
  
  if(args.length == 3){
    [a, b, fn] = args;
  } else if(args.length == 2) {
    [a, fn] = args;
    b = 15;
  } else if(args.length == 1){
    [fn] = args;
    a = 5;
    b = 15;
  } else {
    console.log('Faltan o sobran argumentos');
  }
  
  const [...checks] = checkTypes([
    [a, 'number'], [b, 'number'], [fn, 'function']
  ]);
  
  if(checks.some(pass => !pass)){
    return false;
  }
  
  fn(a, b);
  
  //return true;
}

function logSum(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

function checkType(v, t){
  return typeof v == t;
}

function* checkTypes(variables){
  for(const [v, t] of variables) {
    yield checkType(v, t);
  }
}

show(5, 15, logSum);
show(5, logSum);
show(logSum);

const devuelveFalse = show('');

console.log(devuelveFalse);
```

Comment: ¿Y qué pasa en caso de que el usuario haga `show(5)` y solo espera que la variable `a` sea a la que se le asigne el valor de 5?

Comment: Según he entendido leyendo la pregunta si se llamara a show con un parámetro debería ser c que se pretende que sea una función que se llame con (a, b) como argumentos. @Yikarus

Answer (score 5):

Me gusta la respuesta de deerlopkat, aunque mi aproximacion seria usar "objetos" para emular el comportamiento que muestras.

De este modo:

```js
function shower(){
 
 this.show = function(){
  var sumaA = typeof this.a === 'undefined' ? 15 : this.a;
  var sumaB = typeof this.b === 'undefined' ? 20 : this.b;
  var aEjecutar = typeof this.funcion !== 'function' ?  false : this.funcion;                   
  
  if(!aEjecutar) 
  return false;
  else 
  aEjecutar (sumaA,sumaB);
 }
}


// creamos el objeto
var showerObj = new shower();

//le pasamos los valores a sus propiedades
showerObj.a=5;
showerObj.funcion=function(a,b){
 console.log(a+b);
};

//ejecutamos su metodo.
showerObj.show();
```

En este ejemplo, declaras la "clase" shower,  y como no le asignamos la propiedad "b" toma al valor por defecto que comentas (20). y el resultado en la consola es 25.

claro si si o si quieres llamarlo como parametros, me gusta mucho mas la idea de deerlopkat.

Answer (score 3):

Solo comentar, aparte de lo ya dicho,  que si tienes la suerte de que los parámetros son de tipos distintos, solo tienes que comprobar el tipo y asignarle la variable correspondiente.
Si hay varios del mismo tipo, podrías guardarlo en un vector.
Ejemplo para parámetros de tipo distinto:

```js
 function haceCosas(a,b,c,d,e,f){
  var parametros=[a,b,c,d,e,f];
  var varNumber, varString, varBool, varArray, varObject, varFunction, varObject;
  parametros.forEach(function(p,n){
   document.documentElement.innerHTML+="Parámetro "+n+"= "+typeof p;
   switch (typeof p){
    case "number":
     varNumber=p;
     break;
    case "string":
     varString=p;
     break;
    case "boolean":
     varBool=p;
     break;
    case "function":
     varFunction=p;
     break;
    case "object":
     if  (Array.isArray(p)){
      document.documentElement.innerHTML+=" Array";
      varArray=p;
     }
     else varObject=p;
   }
   document.documentElement.innerHTML+="<br>";

  });
  document.documentElement.innerHTML+="Variable varNumber = "+varNumber+"<br>";
  document.documentElement.innerHTML+="Variable varString = "+varString+"<br>";
  document.documentElement.innerHTML+="Variable varBool = "+varBool+"<br>";
  document.documentElement.innerHTML+="Variable varArray = "+varArray+"<br>";
  document.documentElement.innerHTML+="Variable varObject = "+varObject+"<br>";
  document.documentElement.innerHTML+="Variable varFunction = "+varFunction+"<br>";
 }
 document.documentElement.innerHTML+='haceCosas(1,"a",true,[1,2],document.documentElement,function(){});<br>';
 haceCosas(1,"a",true,[1,2],document.documentElement,function(){});
```

Si los tipos de parámetro pueden repetirse, en vez de varX=parametro, puedes hacer un varX.push(parametro); y gestionarlo luego.
De todas maneras, te aconsejo que los parámetros sean fijos, y de no querer usar uno, simplemente poner un null en su lugar.

Answer (score 2):

Un Ejemplo Simple, es manejar el Error , nunca puedes cambiar los parametros ya definidos por un metodo/funcion

```js
function show(a,b, funcion){
         if (typeof(a) =="undefined" )
           throw "undefined a";
         if (typeof(b) =="undefined" )
           throw "undefined b";          
         if (typeof(b) =="function" )
           throw "b no puede ser una funcion";      
  console.log(`--A : ${typeof a}` , `--B : ${typeof b}` , `--args : ${typeof args}`);
 var aEjecutar = typeof funcion !== 'function' ? 
                 false : funcion;                   
if(!aEjecutar) return false;
else aEjecutar(a,b);

 }

show(5,6 , function(a,b){
    console.log(a+b);
});
show(5,function(a,b){
    console.log(a+b);
});
```

Otra opcion tambien es la que te menciona [@derloopkat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/118092/28035)